# How to I create/import international ferrylines (or flightroutes) into Mapbox

Tags: dictionary, gis, mapbox

I need to add ferrylines/routes (or something similar) into Mapbox, I´m new to "mapping". Do I need to create this data myself or is it downloadable? I need to create routes which crosses oceans.

Reading manual and watching tutorials didn´t help me.

Answer (score 0):

We do provide ferry routes where `class:ferry` in the road layer of the Streets tileset:   
￼

[image]

For overseas routing that does not pertain to ferry routes, you will need to create a custom OSRM routing engine and routing profile. You can find support and documentation here: http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.22.0/api/#general-options.